# How to compare the temporary variables in the form of string?

Tags: c++

I want to know why the two results are different?

the code is：

```
string s1="35",s2="255";
cout<<(s1>s2)<<" "<<("35">"255")<<endl;
```

the output is:

1 0

Comment: That boils down to "how to compare strings". Researching a bit on that topic should be trivial.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I wouldn't say that this question is so trivial. He compares string values both times, but gets different results.

Comment: I didn't want to say that the question is trivial but that it is a trivial topic to do research for. The most difficult task there is to weed out all the bad questions and answers. Adding yet another (IMHO unnecessary) question doesn't make it any easier.

Answer (score 5):

Literal strings in C++ are really arrays of constant characters. As any other array, they decay to pointers to their first element.

With `"35">"255"` you compare the *pointers*, and not the contents of the strings themselves.

To compare literal strings you need to use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). But note that it doesn't return a boolean value.

What you current do is roughly equivalent to

```
char const* a = "35";
char const* b = "255";
std::cout << (&a[0] > &b[0]) << '\n';  // Print the result of comparing the *pointers*
```

---

With `s1>s2` you're invoking the [`operator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) function of `std::string`. The expression `s1 > s2` is equivalent to `s1.operator>(s2)`.

Comment: THX! So ("35">"255") is equal to ("3">"2")?
I want to know, ("35">"255") compares the first element or the pointers?

Comment: I guess:

If compares the elements, the result is determinate. 
If compares the pointers, the result is not determinate. 

If I am wrong, please point it out!

Comment: @Alfred No no no, the string `"35"` and `"3"` are two *different* strings, and their locations could be different, making the ***pointer*** comparison different. Direct comparing literal constant strings just makes no sense.

Comment: why "32"=="32" always return true?

Comment: @Alfred Compilers are allowed to optimize the storage of literal constant strings, so each string is stored only *once*. Therefore `"32" == "32"` compares the *same* pointer for equality. And of course a pointer will be equal to itself.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because "35" and "255" is not an std::string, it is a const char[] (that is, an array of characters). When you declare s1 and s2, the const char[] is converted into an std::string because the type of s1 and s2 is an std::string, but it won't do that automatically.

Running `cout << (s1>s2) << " " << (string("35") > string("255")) << endl` should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strcmp(), that returns a positive or negative value depending on a comparaison of the strings. 
Check out the manual here : [strcmp()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiK-qqzlcDiAhUyAGMBHREmBrsQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fcstring%2Fstrcmp%2F&usg=AOvVaw3hjaC0ro_UGSb_Ayc3AnLS)

Be careful, it takes **const char* and not strings** as arguments.